# What does it mean to rework or remodel an existing composition?

Tags: terminology, production

I was looking at the contributing artists for Ryuichi Sakamoto's album [*ASYNC-REMODELS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASYNC_%E2%80%93_REMODELS), where on the back cover are some terms I wasn't so sure what they meant:

[image]

You can see that the first track is **reworked** by Oneohtrix Point Never, the third is **remodeled** by Alva Noto etc.

What exactly do these terms mean?

Comment: Possibly related: [The four season, recomposed by Max Richter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJnxPgT83rw)

Comment: I think this is totally subjective and can imagine there's some kind of hierarchy, e.g. remodel > rework > remix > edit, with regards to how much they differ from the original